# How to get a Tailwind theme color's actual value from resolveConfig?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-variables

I'm using Next.js and Tailwind. I have a theme defined as a set of CSS vars. How do I access the actual value that results from Tailwind theme colors defined with alphavalue?

When I try to access it via `resolveConfig` I just get the string `rgb(var(--color-one) / <alpha-value>)`, but the result I would like to get is `rgb(255, 0, 0)` or `rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)`.

I need to access it for use inside a TSX component file which has an SVG for two different stopColors in the same gradient. Eventually there will be multiple themes, so its best if I can fetch it since the gradient should change with the theme.

**global.css**

```css
@layer base {
  :root {
    --color-one: 255 0 0;
  }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.tsx', './components/**/*.tsx'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      textColor: {
        skin: {
          one: 'rgb(var(--color-one) / <alpha-value>)',
        }
    },
  }
}
```

**My TSX component**

```js
  const { one } = (twFullConfig?.theme?.textColor as any)?.skin || {}
  console.log(one)
```

This logs `rgb(var(--color-one) / <alpha-value>)` to the console.

How can I get the actual value of the color, `rgb(255,0,0)`, instead of the Tailwind string?

I came up with what feels like an extremely hacky way of doing this: putting classes on a div that is hidden/has no height/width, and then putting a ref on that div, and using `window.getComputedStyles` to access the styles on the div. If there is a better way to do this I'd like to know because this seems like an ugly solution.